# Как сделать преобразование ссылки .htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

Мое апи сейчас доступно по адресу example.com/api/public/api/функция, мне нужно сделать example.com/api/функция

Answer (score 0):

что-то вроде такого

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*) api/public/api/$1 [QSA, L]
```